# How to automatically run two gdb commands upon startup

Tags: gcc, gdb

I find that whenever I start `gdb` I almost always type in:

```
>>> b *main
>>> r
```

And then the program 'starts'. Is there a way I can automatically invoke this, either in a settings, or in the `gdb` invocation itself, such as something like:

```
$ gdb file.o -cmd "b *main; r"
```

Comment: Instead of `b main` followed by `r`, you could also just use [start](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-start).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify startup commands via command line:

```
gdb -ex 'b main' -ex r --args ls -l
```

Comment: thanks that works great: `gdb file.o --ex 'b main' --ex 'r'`. Is it possible to combine multiple commands on a line in `gdb` or do you have to separate all commands on their own line?

Comment: @David542 No, AFAIK it is not possible to combine commands in single line.

Comment: ok thanks, and then finally, what does the `--args ls -l` do? I assume that would pass arguments to `gdb` ? (or are the args passed to the script itself?)

Comment: @David542 `--args` tells gdb that it needs to invoke the program which comes after `--args` with given arguments (`ls -l` in my example). It's not really related to your question so can be removed.